# OpenGL being ported to XNA

Tags: opengl, xna, porting

I'm beginning to port my game over to XNA from a C/OpenGL codebase.  I'm just now getting to the rendering code, and I'm wondering what the best methods would be for transitioning from a system where you simply bind a texture with one call, then output vertex buffers objects to an XNA equivalent set of methods?  I can see how you pass vertex data, but I'm not exactly sure how you bind a texture.  Must it all be done in shaders, or is there a simple procedure for this in XNA?

My main rendering code for models is as follows (I apologize for small variable names)

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, obj->tx);

glColor4f(c.r, c.g, c.b, c.a);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj->iVBO);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, (sizeof(float) * 3) + (sizeof(float) * 2), 0);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, (sizeof(float) * 3) + (sizeof(float) * 2), (const GLvoid*)(4 * 3));
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, obj->iSize);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the MSDN documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.textures.aspx), here is how you bind a texture (two, in fact):

```
graphics.GraphicsDevice.Textures[0] = firstTexture;
graphics.GraphicsDevice.Textures[1] = secondTexture;
```

And then you set your vertex and index buffers (as needed) to the device with the `Indices` property and the `SetVertexBuffer()` method respectively. Then you draw them with one of the `GraphicsDevice.Draw*()` methods.

If you're simply rendering models, then you may want to look into the `Model` class (which will handle this kind of thing for you, including importing models through the content pipeline).

Also, if you're using `BasicEffect`, it also has a  `Texture` member that you can use to handle texturing.

Answer (score 0):

You normally bind the textures to the device using the GraphicsDevice.Textures property.  Code sample is using XNA 4.0.  The port of your code would look something like:

```
        GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise;
        GraphicsDevice.Textures[0] = obj.tx;
        GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(obj.iVBO);

        effectColorParameter.SetValue(c.ToVector4());
        effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();

        GraphicsDevice.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, obj.triangleCount);
        GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(null);
```

Or if you want to use a BasicEffect you bind the texture directly to the effect.

```
        basicEffect.Texture = obj.tx;
        basicEffect.TextureEnabled = true;
```